# Как построить регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text-3

Исходная строка:

```
'First #13#10'#13#10'Second'#13#10#13#10'Third''s'
```

Ожидаемые результаты:

```
First #13#10
Second
Third''s
```

В общем, нужно извлечь все, что находится между `'`. Таких совпадений может быть куча, и все они разделены как минимум одной строкой `#13#10`.

Comment: *все, что находится между `'`* - не понятно почему тогда в результате `First`, а не `First #13#10`.

Comment: результат не подходит под требования. Исходя из требований результат должен быть не ``First``, a ``First #13#10``

Comment: Извиняюсь, исправил.

Comment: Существуют ли сервисы, позволяющие получить регулярное выражение по строке и результатам?

Comment: Вы добавили метку `re`, т.е. это Python?

Comment: Python тут ни причём. Я думал, метка re означает reg exp = регулярные выражения.

Comment: `re` – это библиотека регулярных выражений в Python.

Comment: Так что же вы делаете, хотите получить список совпадений? Попробуйте найти `(?:[^']|'')+\K|^'|'$|'(?:#13#10)+'` и заменить на `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexp: `'((?:''|[^'])+)'`, проверить можно на https://regex101.com/r/vyZBHY/1

```py
# Пример на Python

import re

print(re.findall(r"'((?:''|[^'])+)'", r"'First #13#10'#13#10'Second'#13#10#13#10'Third''s'"))

# output: ['First #13#10', 'Second', "Third''s"]
```

**Update**

Для IDE/редакторов, regexp: `(?<=')(?:''|[^'])+(?='(?:#13#10|$))` - https://regex101.com/r/ZEML54/1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только они должны поддерживать lookahead / lookbehind regexp.

Comment: `'(?:''|[^'])+` также работает. Есть ли разница?

Comment: Такое RE (без групп захвата) будет сопоставляться целиком, и захватит первую кавычку `'` - `'First #13#10`

Comment: У меня и так и сяк первая ковычка захватывается.

Comment: Какой язык/среда/т.п. программирования?

Comment: Использую поиск в Sublime Text (3.2.2, 3211) с учётом RE

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, по ссылке есть пример, там все работает.

Comment: Да, действительно, поторопился. Надо еще как-то предыдущий мэтч учитывать.

Comment: Поиск модулем re в Python получил указанные результаты, но поиск в Sublime Text показал результаты с ковычками. Как же это понимать?

Comment: Сопоставление осуществляется с подстрокой на границах которой присутствуют одинарные кавычки. Дальше, Python берет либо полную подстроку, либо, если присутствуют группы захвата, то подстроку из группы (либо, если групп несколько, то tuple из этих групп). А Sublime берет просто полное соответствие (группу + кавычки).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const regex = /'([^']+(?:[']{2}[^']+)?)'/gm;
const str = `'First #13#10'#13#10'Second'#13#10#13#10'Third''s'`;
let m;

found = str.match(regex);
console.log(found);
```

На примере JavaScript:
`'([^']+(?:[']{2}[^']+)?)'`
Берем символ одинарной кавычки`'`, после него выбираем один и более символов кроме кавычки`[^']+`, создfем необязательную группу `(?:[']{2}[^']+)?` где указываем что могут встретится две одинарные кавычки и после них идет один и более символов не равных символу кавычки/

---

Sublime у меня не установлен, но есть notepad++
Для изменения необходимых строк можно попробовать(**Важно что сначала нужно протестировать**) `[^']*?'([^']+(?:[']{2}[^']+)?)'` шаблон с заменой на первую группу `$1`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Т.е. в поле найти вставляем шаблон `[^']*?'([^']+(?:[']{2}[^']+)?)'`, в поле заменить вставляем `$1\n` захваченную строку + переход на новую строку, должна быть включена поддержка regexp.